# How do I get a list of all elements and their attributes via XQuery

Tags: xquery

I am quite new to XQuery and I am trying to get a list of all elements and all attributes.
It should look like this:


element1 @attributex, @attribue y, ...

element 2 @attribute x, @attribute y, ...

element 3 @attribute x, @attribute y, ...

I am trying this so far, but the error "Item expected, sequence found":

```
for $x in collection("XYZ")
let $att := local-name(//@*)
let $ele := local-name(//*)
let $eleatt := string-join($ele, $att)
return $eleatt
```

I feel like I am turning an easy step into a complicated one. Please help.

Thanks in advance, Eleonore

Answer (score 1):

`//@*` gives you a sequence of attribute nodes, `//*` a sequence of element nodes. In general to apply a function like `local-name()` to each item in a sequence, for nodes you have three options:

1. Use a final step `/local-name()` e.g. `//@*/local-name()` or `//*/local-name()`
2. In XQuery 3.1 use the map operator `!` e.g. `//@*!local-name()`
3. Use a `for .. return` expression e.g. `for $att in //@* return local-name($att)`

Answer (score 1):

The local-name() function takes a single node as its argument, not a sequence of nodes. To apply the same function to every node in a sequence, using the "!" operator: `//*!local-name()`.

The string-join() function takes two arguments, a list of strings, and a separator. You're trying to pass two lists of strings. You want

`string-join((//*!local-name(), //@*!local-name()), ',')`

Of course you might also want to de-duplicate the list using distinct-values(), and to distinguish element from attribute names, or to associate attribute names with the element they appear on. That's all eminently possible. But for that, you'll have to ask a more precise question.

Comment: @michaelhkay Thank you, this is very helpful! I would actually like to distinguish element from attribute names and also associate the respective elements and attributes so that a list is created. Ideally, also referring to the list I put in the original question, it should look like this: - element1 [at]attribute x = "value", [at]attribue y = "value", ... - element 2 [at]attribute x = "value", [at]attribue y = "value", ... Should I add a new question with these ramifications or is a comment sufficient? I have not been here for long. Thanks again!

Comment: It's probably best to raise a new question, being more precise about what output you want. Usually giving one input and the corresponding desired output is enough to make the general requirements clear.