# How to get a list of associated elements and attributes (without duplicates) via XQuery

Tags: xquery

I want to specify my original question (linked below) on how to obtain a list of all elements and their attributes.

What I am looking for is this:

- a list of all elements and their attributes
- so that elements and attributes are associated/it is clear which elements and attributes belong together

- without any duplicates (but if e.g. an attribute is used together with two elements, I want it to be listed with both elements)
- in this manner:

  Element1 @Attribute1, @Attribute2,...

  Element2 @Attribute3, @Attribute4,...

So far, I have tried this:

```
for $x in collection("XYZ")
let $att := local-name(//@*)
let $ele := local-name(//*)
let $eleatt := string-join($ele, $att)
return $eleatt
```

which I modified, after reading a helpful comment by @michaelhkay, to this:

```
for $x in collection("XYZ")
    return distinct-values(string-join(($x//*!local-name(), $x//@*!local-name()), ', &#10;'))
```

However, so far, the elements and attributes are not associated and I am also not sure if all distinct values are gone since I still see some twice (however, they could be used with a variety of elements).

I appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance, 
Eleonore

---

Original question: [How do I get a list of all elements and their attributes via XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956786/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-elements-and-their-attributes-via-xquery/65959681?noredirect=1#comment116685187_65959681)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate duplicate elements by element name I would use

```
for $el in collection("XYZ")//*
group by $name := node-name($el)
return ($name, $el[1]/@*!('@' || node-name())) => string-join(' ')
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVSgeZ/1

Note however, if you group elements that way by their name, you will not distinguish e.g. `<foo att1="value"/>` and `<foo att2="value"/>`, i.e. you would only get the output for one of the `foo` elements. So how/where you want to eliminate duplicates is not quite clear in that context.